# Wordpress migration not working (from windows to unix )

Tags: wordpress

i am developing a website in wordpress on windows. It is working fine on windows . But when i deployed it on my hosting account (unix based) it started misbehaving . Like the edit page is not working , theme customisation page dont open ups , some of the plugins are not working .

I guess this is some file compatibilty issue  between windows and unix . Any one had experienced anything like this in past can please provide some help . I dont want to install a unix environment in my machine and start devlopment from scratch .

Comment: Did you accidentally use the Joomla tag here? as I don't see the purpose

Comment: How did you transfer the site? Plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the file-permissions are not set correctly?
Have a look into the server-log (e.g. /var/www/apache2/error.log or whatever web-server you are using). If you find stuff in there, like "could not open file" or "permission denied"-errors, then this might be the problem.